# Invalid flickr API Key

Tags: rest, ssl, flickr

I am trying to send a simple request to the flickr API just to get a feeling for it.

```
https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.interestingness.getList&api_key(MY API KEY)&date=2014-05-21
```

I recieve to following error message over and over again, does not matter how often I create a new API key

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<rsp stat="fail"> <err msg="Invalid API Key (Key has invalid format)" code="100"/> </rsp>
```

Any ideas? The documentation said that the Flickr API went SSL. But that did not help me alot.

Answer (score 1):

GET parameters are passed like `key=value`. Your GET parameter `api_key` is just a little weird, put the `=`between `api_key` and the key itself like

```
https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.interestingness.getList&api_key=MYAPIKEY&date=2014-05-21
```

and it should work.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string